# How to pass data to Asp.net Web API through Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asp.net-web-api, webclient, query-string

I am wondering how do you send data back and forth when using Windows Phone 7 and asp.net web api?

I have this method in my webapi

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(VerifyUserVm vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        userService.ValidateUser(vm.Email);

        if (userService.ValidationDictionary.IsValid)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage reponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userService.ValidationDictionary.ModelState["Success"]);
            return reponse;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, userService.ValidationDictionary.ModelState);
        }
    }

    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}

public class VerifyUserVm
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and this code in my WP7

```
private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string urlPath = String.Format(WebApiHelp.ApiUrl,"user","get");            
    UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(urlPath);
    uri.Query = "email=" + txtEmail.Text;
    webclient.OpenReadAsync(uri.Uri);
}
```

the url that gets made is this: `http://localhost:50570/api/user/get?email=c`

but the Vm is always null.

Comment: How is your `VerifyUserVm` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web.Api conversationally binds simple parameters (int, string, etc.) form the URL and complex types (any other custom type) from the request body.

If you want to bind a complex type `VerifyUserVm` from the url (e.g.: query string) you need to annotate the parameter with the `FromUriAttribute`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]VerifyUserVm vm)
{
     //..
}
```

One more thing: the casing of the properties should match:

In your VM you have `Email` with a uppercase `E` but you send `email` with a lower case `e`.

So you need to build your parameter like this:

```
uri.Query = "Email=" + txtEmail.Text;
```

For further reading: [How WebAPI does Parameter Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)

Comment: I been looking at RestSharp would this do it automatically for me or would I run into the same problems?

Comment: I have no experience with RestSharp so I have no idea. But as far as I know RestSharp is a client library so I don't know how it can help in your case if you still use web.api on the server side.

Comment: Ok. I tried that and now I get a Vm object but the Email is not populated.

Comment: That casing of the properties should match. In your VM you have `Email` with a capital `E` but you send `email` lower with lower case `e`. Change it to: `uri.Query = "Email=" + txtEmail.Text;`